# Is there a practice mode in Battlefield 1?

Tags: battlefield-1

Battlefield 4 has "Test Range" mode, most notably for practicing the usage of vehicles in an offline environment. I haven't found equivalent in Battlefield 1 and creating private servers appears to cost money (the servers must be rented).

Answer (score 1):

There is no practice mode for BF1.
Your best option is to use the server browser and find an empty server.